# How to connect to Realm Amazon EC2 instance in Android?

Tags: amazon-ec2, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server, realm-java

I created a EC2 instance based on Realm public AMI: ami-9f1522e4. It seems to be working fine.

I am trying to connect to it in Android with the following code

```
    String authUrl= "realm://54.173.116.160:9080/auth"; // 54.173.116.160 is my instance IPv4 public IP
    String serverURL = "realm://54.173.116.160:9080/~/default";
    final SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(myEmail, myPassword, false);

    SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCredentials, authUrl, new SyncUser.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
            final SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, serverURL).build();
            realm = Realm.getInstance(syncConfiguration);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
            Log.e("err", error.getErrorMessage());
        }
    });
```

However this is triggering the onError hook with the following message: Unexpected error.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any further error code?

Comment: What is the `error.getErrorCode()`?

Comment: @beeender error.getErrorCode() gives UNKNOWN(-1)

Comment: what realm object server version are you using? Does it work when you setup the server locally?

Comment: @beeender This is the AMI ID: realm-object-server-pv-20170813 (ami-9f1522e4). I did not try to setup the server locally yet.

Comment: @georges49 Does is help if you switch to `http` or `https` scheme instead of `realm` in `authUrl`?